how to restrict its endpoints with the middleware of adonis js 6 using the custom guard authentication with JWT?
I’m new to adonis js and I’m trying to create a middleware to restrict my endpoints. For my authentication I use custom auth guard (with JWT) documentation.
documentation
my middleware code
export default class AdminMiddleware {
  async handle(
    ctx: HttpContext,
    next: NextFn,
    options: {
      guards?: (keyof Authenticators)[]
    } = {}
  ) {
    const user = await ctx.auth.authenticateUsing(options.guards)

    const isAdmin = Role.MANAGER === user.roleId

    if (!isAdmin) {
      throw new Error("You don't have permission to use this middleware")
    }

    const output = await next()
    return output
  }
}

my route
router
  .group(() => {
    router.post('/add-user', '#controllers/users_controller.addUser')
  })
  .prefix('api/v1/user')
  .use(middleware.admin())

whether the user is the right role or not. it shows that I am not authorized.
result after send a post request
and I have the same result when I use the default middleware auth(). how can I solve this problem
